# Html can not find the flask url

Tags: python, flask

I am doing a small web using python flask, here is the directory structure

[image]

here is the run.py file

```
from app import app
app.run
```

here is the __init__file in app

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, json, request
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('home.html')
    # return "hello"


@app.route('/signin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signin():    
    return 'ok'
```

here is the home.html file

```
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Username">
<input type="text" id="password" class="inbox" placeholder="password">       
<div style="text-align:center">
        <input type="button" id="btn_up_submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="sign up" onclick="upSubmit()">
        <input type="button" id="btn_up_cancel" class="btn btn-success" value="cancel" onclick="upCancel()">
 </div>


<script>
function upSubmit() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();

    mydata = {
        'name':name,
        'password':password
    };   
    $.getJSON('/signin')

}
<script>
```

after I run it, it can show the home.html, but after I　click the submit button, the browser tells me "can not find http://127.0.0.1:8000/signin". Please help me, how to set the url? I want to send args from html to .py file, what should I do. Thanks very much.

Comment: Can I suggest looking at - http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

Comment: @LearningSlowly thanks a lot, I have just began learning python, I will read it.

Comment: No worries. If you go through the entire tutorial you will get a wonderful explanation on how to use flask. Your issue should be resolved by the 3rd tutorial ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by LearningSlowly is worth looking into. Miguel Gringberg wrote a very good Flask tutorial that works perfectly with Python 2.7:
http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

I would recommend trying the different steps with smaller steps. It looks like the issue lies with your javascript implementation. If you were to use curl:

`curl 127.0.0.1:5000/signin`

You should have 'ok' returned to you.

If you want to send data from the .html file to your views.py, I would specifically look at the web forms part of Miguel's tutorial: http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms

It'll help you create a form to send variable to .html, and POST the form fields back to your views.py.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a lot of issues with your code.

- I'm not sure how the flask server is running without you calling `app.run( )` .
- Default flask server runs at port 5000, not 8000.
- It's not clear whether you included jquery. If not, `$`and subsequent jquery functions will not work
- function `upSubmit()` used before declaration

Once you fix these basic issues, it works fine. Check the screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeWK8.jpg).

Comment: Thank for your replay. I had a screenshot of my item directory structure when I asked this question. Run.py is on the last line on the picture. I made a mistake, it should be 5000 not 8000. But I entered 5000 when I run it on my browser.

Comment: And I have included jquery in my html, just did not write it on my question. I added upSubmit() at the back of input tag. Thanks

Comment: What I meant was, in your run.py file, you are not calling function app.run() [note the parentheses]. Is the problem solved now?